# Should I specify 'reference=train_set' when creating a evaluating lightgbm.Dataset?

Tags: dataset, model-evaluations, normalization, lightgbm, inference

According to the [docs](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.Dataset.html), we should offer a argument `reference=train_set` when creating a validating lightgbm.Dataset.

I know a little about the reason, i.e. there are some statistics data inside the training set object, such as average values and std-dev of every features, to be used when 'normalizing' the validating set.

My question is:
**Should I do the same when creating a evaluating/testing/infering set?**

For example:

```
lgb_train = lgb.Dataset(x_train, y_train)
lgb_valid = lgb.Dataset(x_valid, y_valid, reference=lgb_train)
model = lgb.train(params, train_set=lgb_train, valid_sets=lgb_valid)
model.save_model('model.txt')

# Should I offer `reference=lgb_train` in the following line?
lgb_eval = lgb.Dataset(eva_feats, eva_labls, reference=lgb_train)
predicts = model.predict(lgb_eval)
```